# How to check multiple variables for undefined at the same time?

Tags: typescript

Given some list of variables, I'd like to check that all of them are not undefined, before I run my code.

My code below has 4 variables which may or may not be undefined. I can manually check a and b and make tsc happy that those are always numbers.

But I want a solution that saves me typing, so I've tried to implement a function to check several variables in one go. Unfortunatly I can't make it work without losing type information, so tsc dislikes the code.

I'm running this with `strictNullChecks` on.

```
let a = func1(),
    b = func1(),
    c = func1(),
    d = func1();

function func1() {
  return Math.random() === 0 ? 1 : undefined; 
}

function func2(a: number, b: number) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}

function anyUndef(a: any[]): boolean {
  return a.filter(e => typeof e === 'undefined').length > 0;
}

if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && typeof b !== 'undefined') {
  func2(a, b);
}

if (!anyUndef([c, d])) {
  func2(c, d);
}
```

Comment: You have `strictNullChecks` enabled ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yeah, I run with `strict`. Generally as strict as I can make it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that flow control checking will not take into account checks performed inside called functions. We can use a type guard, but type guards can only assert the type of a single parameter. To get around this we can use tuple types:

```
function allDef<T, T2, T3, T4>(a: [T | undefined, T2 | undefined, T3 | undefined, T4 | undefined]): a is [T, T2, T3, T4] 
function allDef<T, T2, T3>(a: [T | undefined, T2 | undefined, T3 | undefined]): a is [T, T2, T3] 
function allDef<T, T2>(a: [T | undefined, T2 | undefined]): a is [T, T2] 
function allDef<T>(a: [T | undefined]): a is [T] 
function allDef(a: any[]): boolean{
    return a.filter(e => typeof e === 'undefined').length > 0;
}
// Helpers for inferring tuple types
function tuple<T, T2, T3, T4>(a: [T, T2, T3, T4]): typeof a 
function tuple<T, T2, T3>(a: [T, T2, T3]): typeof a 
function tuple<T, T2>(a: [T, T2]): typeof a 
function tuple<T>(a: [T]): typeof a 
function tuple(a: any): typeof a{
    return a;
}

var x = tuple([c, d]); // create the tuple
if (allDef(x)) { // use the type assertion
    [c, d] = x; // restore the values to the variables, they will not be undefined
    func2(c, d);
}
```

Not sure if this is better then the manual checking, but it works, maybe for more variables it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, it's a shame it can't be made shorter. If I needed to do similar checks a lot of times, perhaps it would be worthwhile; but for all my current use-cases, this would add quite a bit more code than it would save.

Comment: @Letharion yeah, I figured it's a bit convoluted, but it was fun to write :). Unfortunately for now I think this is the only solution, although I hope to be proved wrong :)

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10734 which appears to be related. It hasn't gotten a lot of attention though, so it doesn't look like it will be implemented any time soon.